# Retrieving Database Data to JSON - Mobile Login Form

Tags: javascript, php, json, cordova

Im creating Mobile App using Phonegap that first need to login. if login success It will retrieve the data to JSON.

This is the PHP page that connects to mobile site and retrieve the data.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password,$mysql_database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}else{
    //echo 'ok';
}

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if (!$result) {
  //die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  $data = array('status'=>'failure','Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}else {
    //$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $details = array(
                        'id'=>$row['id'],
                        'username'=>$row['username'],
                        'email'=>$row['email'],
                        'password'=>$row['password'],
                        'repassword'=>$row['repassword'],
                    );
    $data = array('status'=>'success','data'=>$details);
}
echo json_encode($data);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

but it doesnt work properly.
I'm following my lecturer Code. but i think he has missed something

here my HTML content

```
<script>
    function login(){

var uName=$("#loginID").val();
var pwd=$("#pwdID").val();

$.post("http://boost.meximas.com/mobile/verifying.php", { username: uName, password: pwd },
   function(json){
console.log(json);
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json );
console.log(obj.status);
if(obj.login == "success"){
alert("success");
}
else
alert("Incorrect user name or password");
});
}
    </script>


<div data-role="content">
                <Table>
    <tr><td>Login</td>
    <td><input class="fld" id="loginID" name="txtNum1" type="text" value="" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password</td>
    <td><input class="fld" id="pwdID" name="txtNum1" type="text" value="" /></td></tr>

</Table>
    <a class="ui-button" data-role="button" onClick="login();" data-transition="slide" id="flipid" >Login</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you have any error messages? What is the value of $data after the login POST - also unrelated, this code should never be on a public facing webserver, it is succeptable to SQL injection. IE: if i posted a password as "' OR '1'='1" your code will return a valid user for any password. - You need to escape any user input before sending it to the database.

Comment: Yeah i know. it is very primary level of coding. but i wanted to do is here is retrieve the database data into that JSON object, you can see My url by clicking http://boost.meximas.com/mobile/verifying.php I'm getting some null values.. but I'm referring my lecturer link and it not gives that result http://talenweave.com/LeaveApp/login.php

Comment: Have you got a link to the HTML?

Comment: i don't think its nothing to do with HTML page. because we first did login to this  talenweave.com/LeaveApp/login.php, and i wanted to make my own php page to check how it works..

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues I can see off the bat:

1. You are testing if `isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])` but, you are not actually catching the case where they are not set, and you are continuing to execute the code with null/empty values.
2. the SQL injection issue I mentioned in my comment to your question, you should never let this code be visible on a public facing website.

Without more detail, I am unable to say if the issue lies with the HTML, the PHP or the JavaScript.

I would change change the if/else when testing the username/password to return something like: `$data = array('status'=>'failure','Error' => 'Invalid username/password');` when the username/password is not set.

I hope this helps.